# OpenCV: Returning Point type from a function to main

Tags: c++, opencv

Compiling on Windows with MSVS2010

I need to write a function that will accept a Mat image and return std::vector< Point > points;. But I am unable to understand what will be return type in function definition.

```
Point collectpoints(Mat image)  //return type???

{

std::vector<Point> points;

//calculated  points here, and now want to return the points to main()// 


return points  //this has error 

}


int main

{
   int X1=0, Y1=0, X2=0, Y2=0;
 Mat img = imread("chhha.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);

std::vector<Point> points1;

points1 = colectpoints(img); //type casting required?  

//now check the collected points

X1=points[0].x; 
X2=points[1].x; 


Y1=points[0].y; 
Y2=points[1].y; 
cout<<"First and second X  coordinates are given below"<<endl;
cout<<X1<<'\t'<<X2<<endl; 

cout<<"First and second Y coordinates are given below"<<endl;
cout<<Y1<<'\t'<<Y2<<endl; 

return 0;
}
```

The above is not working and I am not sure how exactly should I return the value of points.

Basically the errors are:

```
 error C2664: 'cv::Point_<_Tp>::Point_(const cv::Point_<_Tp> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const cv::Point_<_Tp> &'   plotfunction.cpp   272


 IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::vector<cv::Point, std::allocator<cv::Point>>" to "cv::Point" exists    plotfunction.cpp   272
```

both the errors on `return points`

Can somebody tell me how to correctly return points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function signature is saying that the function returns a single Point (in this case, cv::Point), when it looks like you're trying to return the full list of them.  To return the collection, your function definition should look like:

```
std::vector<Point> collectPoints(Mat image)
{
    std::vector<Point> points;
    ...
    return points;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW if I have to pass points as an argument , can I do like this: foo(Mat image, std::vector<Point> points)